# Error Timestamp format

Tags: java, oracle, timestamp

I'm trying to retrieve a `Timestamp` from my DB and I need to convert it to a `java.util.Date`

I've been following several examples I've found in stackoverflow but I keep getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
```

I don't know why, I've tried several ways of doing this, can you help me?

Here's my code:

```
//select all partitions from table "LDRS"
stmtSelect = connection.prepareCall("Select HIGH_VALUE from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'LDRS'");

ResultSet rs = stmtSelect.executeQuery();

SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

while (rs.next()) {
    try {
        Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp("HIGH_VALUE");
        Date date1 = myFormat.parse(ts.toString());
        Date date2 = myFormat.parse(""+new Date());
        // compares the current date with the partition date, if the difference between them is more than 30 days
        // drops the partition
        long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop converting the values to strings and back. A `java.sql.Timestamp` already *is* a `java.util.Date`:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

while (rs.next()) {
    Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp("HIGH_VALUE");
    long diff = ts.getTime() - now;
    ... use diff ...
}
```

You should *only* be dealing with strings when you fundamentally want to do so. In this case, "finding the difference between a stored timestamp and the current time" has nothing to do with a string representation.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to tell. I need the difference in days of the two dates, 5 days, 10 days, etc... I can't do that with mills, can I?

Comment: @MyNameIsRui: *Where* do you get that exception? You didn't provide a stack trace, and the code I've provided would *not* give that issue as it doesn't perform any parsing. As for converting into days - you need to think about what you want to do with time zones. If you're happy to treat a day as *always* being 24 hours, you can just divide the milliseconds by "the number of milliseconds in 24 hours" - but that will mean that you'll get odd results if you consider the *local* time.

Comment: Nevermind, my mistake, your code works fine. Tks